# Order of the lines on makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have main.cpp (including main function) and func1.cpp, and I want to link these files with a makefile. Classic form would be:

```
main: main.o func1.o
    g++ main.o func1.o -o main
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
func1.o: func1.cpp
    g++ -c func1.cpp
```

or one can write

```
main: func1.o main.o 
    g++ main.o func1.o -o main
func1.o: func1.cpp
    g++ -c func1.cpp
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

or

```
main: main.o func1.o
    g++ main.o func1.o -o main
func1.o: func1.cpp
    g++ -c func1.cpp
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

Do the last two differ from the classic one ? Does one have some advantages over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only time the order of the *rules* comes into play is when you just enter `make`, in which case it can choose the first rule as the default.

Beyond that, `make` is intelligent enough to execute dependent rules no matter where they are in the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the three sets of ruls.  However, `make` knows how build `.cpp` files into object files, so all you really need is:

```
main: main.o func1.o
        g++ main.o func1.o -o $@
```

Comment: Or perhaps `g++ $^ -o $@` to avoid repeating yourself.